# iPad virtual keyboard text entry: Can I disable the automatic upper-casing that takes place after I end a sentence?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, text-input

When using the iPad to type a note, for instance, every time I type a period, the iPad assumes I want to start the next word with a capital letter.  It also assumes I want to start typing with a capital letter in some text fields on web forms.  Is there any way to turn off the automatic SHIFT that is taking place, so there are only capital letters where I explicitly want them to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to settings
2. Go to general
3. Go to keyboard
4. Toggle and disable auto-capitalization